# componentWillMount not updating state based on props initially

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, lifecycle

I  have 1 component, which receives a prop from the parent component, the prop is a firebase Array of objects.

Something like `[{date:"string", value:"number"},{...},{...}...]`

My idea is to have the array of objects and loop it using a cycle and display the average of some values in a `<p></p>` tag

So I did this

```
componentDidMount(){
   let sum = 0 , avr;
   for(let i = 0; i < this.props.fuelD.length; i++){
     sum += parseInt(this.props.fuelD[i].value);
   }
   avr = ( sum / this.props.fuelD.length).toFixed(2);

   this.setState({averageFuelConsumption:avr})
}
```

the JSX is this

```
<p>Average: {this.state.averageFuelConsumption}</p>
```

So the problem I'm getting is this ...

On the initial (first) mounting for `{this.state.averageFuelConsumption}` I  get a `NaN` ..  but when I load some other component and then load the old one I get the average value calculated.

I know about the componentWillReciveProps and other methods ...  but I don't know how to use then I this case ... and also my idea is that the props itself will be populated later on and I  want dynamically to calculate the average .. each time a new object is written in the database and then pulled and loaded as a prop in the parent component.

Comment: Have you tried setting the initial state for the component, so you can later change it with the `componentDidMount()` method?

Comment: ofc ... the initial  state is  0 in  the constructor

Comment: is `props.fuelD` being fetched from an API server?

Comment: yes , Google Firebase

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using state or lifecycle methods entirely. Just use a function that calculates and returns the average fuel consumption and call it in your render method.

```
    calculateAverageConsumption() {
      if (!this.props.fuelD) return 0;

      let sum = 0 , avr;
      for(let i = 0; i < this.props.fuelD.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(this.props.fuelD[i].value);
      }
      avr = ( sum / this.props.fuelD.length).toFixed(2);

      return avr;
    }
```

Then just call it in your render method:

```
<p>Average: {this.calculateAverageConsumption()}</p>
```

The component will rerender and call `this.calculateAverageConsumption()` every time it receives new props.

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.calculateAverageConsumption();
}

calculateAverageConsumption = () => {
   if (!this.props.fuelD) return 0;

   let sum = 0 , avr;
   for(let i = 0; i < this.props.fuelD.length; i++){
      sum += parseInt(this.props.fuelD[i].value);
   }

   avr = ( sum / this.props.fuelD.length).toFixed(2);

   this.setState({
     averageFuelConsumption: avr
   })
}

render() {
  return (
    <p>Average: {this.state.averageFuelConsumption}</p>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

So, recalculate `averageFuelConsumption` whenever the prop changes.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { averageFuelConsumption: this.calcAverage(props.fuelD) };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ averageFuelConsumption: this.calcAverage(nextProps.fuelD) });
}

calcAverage(array) {
  if (!array) 
    return 0;

  const sum = array.reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0);
  return (sum / array.length).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: in `componentWillReceiveProps`, you need to use `nextProps` in the `calcAverage` method call: `this.calcAverage(nextProps.fuelD)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that your data hasn't loaded the first time the component is mounted, can you log the data before you perform your calculations? If this is the case, calculating the value in the render method is a good idea since it will be called again each time the props change. componentDidMount is only called the first time.